# My DB class wont connect, throws exception "No database selected"

Tags: php, oop

I have my 'dbinterface' class with a connect function. When i run this i get a statement saying "Query didn't work. No database selected"

```
class dbinterface {

        private $_dbLink;
    private $dbHost = 'host';
        private $dbUser = 'user';
        private $dbName = 'name';
        private $dbPass = 'pass';
        private $dbUserTable = 'table';

     public function connect ()
    {
        $this->_dbLink = mysql_connect($this->_dbHost, $this->_dbUser, $this->_dbPass);
        if(!$this->_dbLink) 
            throw new Exception ("Could not connect to database. " . mysql_error());
    }
```

I made a change to the public connect function.

```
public function connect ()
    {
        $this->dbLink = mysql_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass);
        mysql_select_db($this->dbUserTable);
        if(!$this->dbLink) 
            throw new Exception ("Could not connect to database. " . mysql_error());
    }
```

Unfortunately it output the same result. I am new to PHP and still learning, i have tried everything i know so ANY help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You get a 'No DB select' exception but you show the 'could not connect' exception code?

Comment: You really should switch to PDO.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use an absolute `schema.table` type reference in your queries, you HAVE to specify a default database with `mysql_select_db()`. Without that,

```
SELECT somefield FROM sometable
```

fails with "no database selected" because MySQL doesn't know WHICH database it should look in for that table.

This would work, however:

```
SELECT somefield FROM name_of_db.name_of_table
```

without a default database, as you've explicitly stated you're using the "name_of_db" database.